# Elasticsearch query returning deleted record(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have this odd bug with elasticsearch returning a hit on a record that should have been(and seems to be) deleted.

Here is my app structure:

- Rails Api using Searchkick to manage ES indices
- ES version 5.6
- Angular web app that queries ES directly

Normal use case is that all managing of the indices is done through searchkick, but the frontend app sends queries directly to the ES server instead of through the searchkick interface(The rails api services many other frontend apps).

I run a script that will delete a record from my database, which should async match to my ES index. For example if I delete a record with id=12345 then when I do MyModel.search 12345 searchkick fails to return that record since it is no longer in the index.

However, on the front-end application when I query the ES index directly it actually does return the record! Here is an example of the ES query I am using which returns exactly 1 hit (the deleted record). Another thing to note is that this doesn't happen all the time, but occasionally pops up leaving around ghost records.

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"id":"12345"}},{"nested":{"path":"nested_object","inner_hits":{"size":100},"query":{"bool":{}}}}],"should":[]}},"size":30,"from":0,"sort":["_score",{"updated_at":"asc"}]}
```

Does anyone have insight into why my searchkick query and direct ES query are disagreeing on this deleted record?

Comment: How long do you wait before delete and query? You might be a victim of the "commit interval" if this is a very short time in between. Elasticsearch commits changes to disk as batches every so often, instead of modifying disk for each index/delete operation.

Comment: What is your refresh value? (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html)  . You can also force a refresh after a query.